# Location Listener cannot be stopped after onDestroy()

Tags: java, android, android-activity, location, android-lifecycle

I have an app with two buttons that start and stop GPS tracking. I would like the user to be able to leave the app while it is running, but continue tracking location while doing so. Upon returning the user should be able to stop the tracker using the stop button. Simple enough.

The issue is that the Location Listener cannot be stopped (removeUpdates) after the app has been closed and reopened. I believe this is because the Location Manager created in onCreate() is being tied to a new instance of Location Listener that is not the same as the one left running in the background when the app first closes.

I cannot assign Location Manager during declaration because it requires a Context.

My declarations:

```
LocationManager myLocMan;
LocationListener myLocList = new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        //Do things
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
};
```

Here is the relevant code from onCreate():

```
myLocMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 0, myLocList);
            startButton.setEnabled(false);
            stopButton.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

stopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        myLocMan.removeUpdates(myLocList);
        startButton.setEnabled(true);
        stopButton.setEnabled(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi welcome to stackoverflow. have u removed the location listener in onDestroy(or onStop) and it still keeps listening?

Comment: if you want to use location service after user leaves the app, you will have to move it to the service

Comment: Kamyar, I was hoping to keep the listener running while the app is closed, I just run into issues when it is reopened. Vladyslav, I see, I will have to figure out the best way to put it into a background service. I thought it was working because the location continues to track after the app is closed. Thank you both